# a voucher for a front row seat?

Tags: vocabulary, collocations

Does it make sense to say "a voucher for a front row seat," meaning a free ticket for a front row seat at a performance?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what it means.

Answer (score 3):

"A voucher for a front row seat" can be exchanged for a ticket. It might not be tied to a particular day or performance. However, if you mean "A free ticket" then just say "A free ticket".

> The first prize is a voucher for a front row seat at any play at The Apollo theatre this summer.
>
> Jack is sick and couldn't go to the theatre, so I got a free ticket to see Hamlet this evening.

Comment: Someone told me "voucher for a front row seat" is incorrect; he said "ticket for a front row seat" should be correct. What do you think?

Comment: Please read my answer above, where I explain exactly what I think.